# Removing duplicate element from a list and the element itself

Tags: python, list, unique

I know this question has been asked lots of times, but I am not asking how to remove duplicate elements from a list only, I want to remove the duplicated element as well.

For example, if I have a list:

```
x = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 5]
```

I want the list to be:

```
x = [2, 3, 4] # removed 1 and 5 since they were repeated
```

I can't use a `set`, since that will include `1` and `5`.

Should I use a `Counter`? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be done with a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) object. It's trivial.

```
from collections import Counter
x = [k for k, v in Counter([1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 5]).iteritems() if v == 1]
print x
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: +1. Maybe: k, v -> (k, v) / "k" -> item / "v" -> "occurrences". And "iteritems" -> "items" in py3.0

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this way:

```
[_ for _ in x if x.count(_) == 1]
```

EDIT: This is not the best way in term of time complexity as you can see in the comment above, sorry my mistake.

Comment: This is `O(n^2)`. Using a dict or Counter gives you `O(n)` and isn't really any harder.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
duplicates = set(x)
x = [elem for elem in x if elem not in duplicates]
```

This has the advantage of being O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Edit. Indeed my bad, I must have been half asleep. Mahmoud's answer above is the correct one.

Comment: Your `duplicates` isn't the set of duplicates, it's the set of all elements, and x will end up empty, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

Something more verbose and O(n):

```
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

def counts_fold(acc, x):
    acc[x] = acc[x]+1 if x in acc else 1
    return acc

counts = reduce(counts_fold, x, {})

y = [i for i in x if counts[i] == 1]

print y
```

Comment: The OP was already suggesting using `Counter`, why on earth would he like to duplicate its functionality?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that last line. I think I forgot about the Counter stuff some time ago, nice to be reminded of it.